# Can I really edit my Telegram messages only with the desktop client?

Tags: instant-messaging, telegram, editing

I use Telegram both on my desktop and my mobile phone. On the desktop, I can edit messages I've sent, but on the mobile Telegram client I can't find this option anywhere. Does it really not exist or am I missing something. Or - should I look for an unofficial client for this feature?

Note:

- If I tap a message in a Telegram conversation view, the 'Message' context menu only has "Reply|Copy|Forward|Delete" - and no "Edit".
- My client version is `4.9.1 (1361) arm-v7a`

Comment: this feature is universal to all latest official versions of telegram. make sure that you are using the latest version.

Comment: @tashakori: Well, I think I am. Would you mind adding an answer with a screenshot of where in the UI I can access the edit functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple *tap* on a message you sent recently will bring up the action menu containing "Edit".

[image: IMG:]

Comment: My 'Message' menu doesn't have Edit! - it has: Reply, Copy, Forward, Delete - and that's it.

Comment: Maybe emphasis on "sent recently"? Clicking one of the older messages will not show Edit here either. My TG client is not the latest but I believe TG didn't make any feature regression.

Comment: Please add this comment to your answer (or just replace your answer with the comment.